# can we convert String formatted date dd/mm/yyyyy to Date type in same format?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm using struts2.x with jquery date picker.
I want to dispaly in the format dd/mm/yyyy. But from the database when fetching it is coming like yyyy-mm-dd.Then i converted it into the required format but the type is String. So next i Converted it to Date type. But the format is changed.

```
Date getRiskCommDate()
{
String fString = null;
System.out.println("Coming Date from DB"+riskCommDate);
if(riskCommDate!=null)
{
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
format.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
fString = format.format(riskCommDate);
}
System.out.println("Formated Date in  String Form "+fString);
Date d = new Date(fString);
System.out.println("Formated Date in Date form Date "+d);
return d;  
}
```

Output :

> Coming Date from DB  2012-07-04
>       Formated Date in  String Form     04/07/2012
>       Formated Date in Date form Date   Sat Apr 07 00:00:00 IST 2012

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class does not have any property to hold a format.

To display the value of the `Date` in a custom format, call the [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-) method on [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

When you do this:

```
System.out.println(dateInstance)
```

…you are simply calling the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) on the `Date`. That method returns the date in fixed format in `String` version.

**Based on the comments**

If you anyhow wants the custom format with date instance then you can either create a custom class wrapping date instance

```
class MyDate{
  private Date date;
  //provide appropriate accessor
  //override toString() method to support required output
}
```

or `extend` `Date`

```
class MyDate extends Date{
   //override toString() method to support required output
   @Override
   public String toString(){
        //convert `this` to  String with required format with the help of `SimpleDateFormat`
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jigar, I need to convert it to Date format at any cost. Else my application will not work at all.. So any possibility there to do that?

Comment: Then what would be the solution.. I need to return the format of dd/mm/yyyy of Date type. But not String type

Comment: create a utility method that takes date as input and provides format String as a result of method

Comment: That i'm already doing here.Taking Date and converting to Formatted String... But when i convert it to Date type then format is changing.. I'm bit in tension to solve it..

Answer (score 2):

Date prints a format based on the Locale.  It doesn't "remember" the format you gave it want you constructed it.  Only Strings have a particular format, so if you need that, keep it as a String.

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm inserting the same data member into the database with Date as the column type.So i should have to convert to date only...

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The old troublesome date-time libraries bundled with early Java have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. For Java 6 & 7, use the back-port, ThreeTen-Backport, and for Android the adaption thereof, ThreeTenABP. Avoid using the old java.util.Date/.Calendar and such.

## `LocalDate`

The java.time classes include [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

## `java.sql.Date`

Hopefully JDBC drivers will be updated to deal directly with java.time types. Until then, use java.sql types for moving data in/out of database. The old java.sql classes have new [`to…`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--) and [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDate-) methods for conversion with java.time. Our interest here is in [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).

```
LocalDate localDate = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

You can go the other direction, for submission to the database.

```
java.sql.Date myJavaSqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

## Generate String

None of the discussed date classes (java.util.Date, java.sql.Date, java.time.LocalDate) have any “format”. Only textual representations of their values have a format. If you need a String, those classes can generate a String object for you. But do not confuse that String object with a date-time object as they are entirely separate and distinct.

The `toString` method on `LocalDate` use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format such as `2012-07-04` (meaning July 4, 2012).

```
String outputIso8601 = localDate.toString();
```

For other formats, use a `DateTimeFormatter`. Many other Questions and Answers on Stack Overflow have more discussion.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
String output = localDate.format( formatter ); // Generates a textual representation of the object’s date-only value.
```

Better yet, let java.time localize for you.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT );
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ); // or Locale.US, and so on.
String output = localDate.format( formatter );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).